# Range1.Range2 returns strange addresses

Tags: excel, vba

When I have used Range1.Range2, I have used Range2 to expand or contract Range1.  While attempting to answer a question, I encountered a use where Range2 had no relationship to Range1.  I assumed this would return an error but instead it returned an address which I do not understand.

This macro:

```
Sub Test()

  Debug.Print Range("A2").Range("B1").Address
  Debug.Print Range("B3").Range("B5").Address
  Debug.Print Range("C4").Cells(10, 5).Address
  Debug.Print Range("D5").Cells(10, 15).Address
  Debug.Print Range("D5:F10").Cells(10, 15).Address
  Debug.Print Cells(5, 6).Cells(12, 15).Address
  Debug.Print "======"
  ' Specifying the sheet does not seem to affect the result
  Debug.Print Range("B3").Cells(15, 1).Address
  Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Cells(15, 1).Address
  Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Cells(15, 1).Address

End Sub
```

produces this output:

```
$B$2
$C$7
$G$13
$R$14
$R$14
$T$16
======
$B$17
$B$17
$B$17
```

In all the tests of this type I have performed, it appears:

```
Range1.Range2
```

is equivalent to:

```
Cells(Range1.Row + Range2.Row - 1, Range1.Column + Range2.Column - 1)
```

I hope I am not about to experience a DOH moment but is anyone able to offer an explanation?

I am using Excel 2003.  Do users of other releases get the same output from this macro?

Comment: When Range applied to a Range object, the property is relative to the Range object. For example, if the selection is cell C3, then Selection.Range("B1") returns cell D3 because it’s relative to the Range object returned by the Selection property. (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834676.aspx))

Comment: @simoco  Thanks for that link which I had not encountered before.  I will have to try to rationalise this behaviour to myself.  To me it seems to be duplicating the behaviour of Offset object.

Comment: Yes, you're right! They quite similar, i.g. `Range("C3").Range("B1:C3").Address`  gives the same result as `Range("C3").Offset(0, 1).Resize(3, 2).Address`

Comment: @simoco.  Turn your comment into an answer for me to accept; you deserve the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As follows from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834676.aspx):

> When Range applied to a Range object, the property is relative to the Range object. For example, if the selection is cell C3, then Selection.Range("B1") returns cell D3 because it’s relative to the Range object returned by the Selection property.

And as @Tony noticed, behaviour of `Range.Range` quite similar to `Offset.Resize`, i.e. `Range("C3").Range("B1:C3").Address` returns the same address as `Range("C3").Offset(0, 1).Resize(3, 2).Address` –– `$D$3:$E$5`