# Copy and Pasting Special?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to perform a formula on column "K", change its format and then copy and paste it in column "A".

I am also trying to copy and paste column "I" to column "B". "i" determines the numebr of cells in column B.

here is my code so far:

```
Sub Test()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   With Range("K3:K" & i)
        .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
        .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
        .Copy
        Range("A3:A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End With
   With Range("I3:I" & i)
        .Copy
        Range("B3:B" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End With

End Sub
```

Any ideas where I went wrong? I am new to VBA so this is most likely a minor mistake I am overlooking.

Edit: The adjusted formula is copying Column I to Column B properly, but Column K to Column A is wrong.

Lets say column K has the dates:

```
29Apr1921
08May1922
21Oct1923
```

Column A now has:

```
04Apr1905
05Apr1905
06Apr1905
```

Comment: What unexpected result are you seeing? An error? No result? Wrong formatting? Others?

Comment: remove period `.` before range in this lines `.Range("A3:A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` and `.Range("B3:B" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`. When using `.` before range you get `Range("K3:K" & i).Range("A3:A" & i)` which is works like `offset`+`resize`. You could read more about `Range.Range` behaviour here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417748/range1-range2-returns-strange-addresses/21424687#21424687

Comment: Thank you simoco, it copied and pasted . The only issue is that in column A the dates were not transferred properly. I'll explain in a edit in the question.

Comment: @JC11, it's because you copies *only formats* from column K to column A. Let say your column A contains some values. After applying date format all values would be displayed as dates: 1 -> 01Jan1900 , 2->02Jan1900 and so on.

Comment: I see, I need to add in xlPasteValues! I'm going to paste the answer, but is entitely thanks to your comments, so I will accept it from you if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it was missing paste values and was only pasting the format. It also needed its own With statement after the Date formula was performed.

```
Sub Test()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   With Range("K3:K" & i)
        .Formula = "=DATE(A3,G3,H3)"
        .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyyyy"
End With
   With Range("K3:K" & i)
   .Copy
    Range("A3:A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A3:A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End With

   With Range("I3:I" & i)
        .Copy
        Range("B3:B" & i).PasteSpecial

   End With

End Sub
```